# Do inline-block divs work when printing?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, printing

I have a pretty complex single-page application for managing data. Among other things, it of course needs to be able to print that data. For the most part I have my hands around what does and doesn't actually work when printing from the browser, and the tricks you can play in CSS using the @page directive.

I hit a problem last week that I'm finding a bit mystifying, though. I'm trying to print data onto cardstock forms -- for example, printing name badges on cardstock that might be 2 columns by 4 rows per page. I'm trying to do this using fixed-side divs, where the div's CSS looks something like this:

```
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5in;
  height: 2.5in;
}
```

That displays fine on-screen, but when I go to print it, it is coming out with each badge on a separate line -- the divs don't seem to be inlining properly. Margins are minimal, so I don't *think* that's the issue.

I'm at a loss here. Does fixed-size inline-block not work when printing? I'm using Chrome, if that's relevant. I am hoping that's it's possible to make this work without, eg, resorting to generating the pages as PDF on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<style>
  .container {
    width: 7in; /* This guarantees there will be enough room for 2 badges side-by-side */
  }

  .badge {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* You only need this if you add padding or borders */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3.5in;
    height: 2.5in;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="badge">
    Badge 1
  </div><div class="badge"> <!-- DO NOT put line breaks between the badge divs! -->
    Badge 2
  </div><div class="badge">
    Badge 3
  </div><div class="badge">
    Badge 4
  </div>
</div>
```

In short, the 7in wide container div guarantees you'll have enough width to fit two badges side-by-side. Also, there are no line breaks between the badge divs, because line breaks would turn into spaces, which would prevent the badges from fitting beside eachother. Finally, I added `box-sizing: border-box` to the badge CSS to ensure that the width won't exceed 3.5in if you add borders or padding.

Answer (score 0):

The number of depends on your screen size.
so when the resolution of the screen change or the printed page has another size, The number of rows and columns.
so i suggest to you to use `%` as unit instead of `in`  to re-size width and height or make an css style for each resolution. Or you can Use the `HTML table tag`.

Because the `inline-block` Just treats the element like other "inline elements" and allows the use of block properties. it does not precise how many column and row.

Comment: The whole point is that this is for printing on form stock: the sizes *are* hardcoded, physically.  And table tags are inappropriate for situations like this, where all I care about is printing individual cells, and don't actually care about row/column.